# What hosting service has tools for deploying web apps written in Elm?

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, elm

I see some tips on using Heroku to host Elm webs apps. Does Heroku or any other hosting service provide advantages for Elm developers?

Comment: You deploy compiled code - any hosting will work well

Answer (score 5):

Elm compiles to JavaScript that is served as a static file, and execution occurs solely in the user's browser. Deploying an Elm application just consists of uploading these static files, and there are no advantages a host could offer to make Elm any easier.

Even if you'd prefer to upload the Elm files and compile them on the server itself, the Elm compiler is an ordinary executable or an NPM module, so what that comes down to is a Node environment or ability to execute an arbitrary program, not any special Elm environment.

Comment: The easiest out there would be Firebase Hosting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) its like, `firebase init`  - `firebase deploy` and you get a CDN'd blazing fast hosting for your frontend applications. I run an Elm project on there.